What is the difference between `&mut *transaction` and `&mut transaction` in SQLx?
I'm curious what the difference is between &mut *transaction and &mut transaction in my example since I didn't think that transaction was a pointer to begin with but for some reason &mut *transaction satisfies the trait constraint while &mut transaction does not.
Here is my working code:
use sqlx::{PgPool, Transaction, Executor};
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};

pub struct SimpleDbClient {
    db: PgPool,
}

pub trait AddCharacterEntries {
    async fn insert_character_entries(&self, timestamp: DateTime<Utc>, char_values: Vec<(char, i32)>) -> sqlx::Result<()>;
}

impl AddCharacterEntries for SimpleDbClient {
    async fn insert_character_entries(&self, timestamp: DateTime<Utc>, char_values: Vec<(char, i32)>) -> sqlx::Result<()> {
        let mut transaction = self.db.begin().await?;
        for (character, ascii_value) in char_values {
            sqlx::query!(
                r#"
                INSERT INTO character_log (timestamp, character, ascii_value)
                VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
                "#,
                timestamp,
                character as char,
                ascii_value
            )
            .execute(&mut *transaction)
            .await?;
        }
        transaction.commit().await?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

If I change the above to .execute(&mut transaction) I get this error:
rustc: the trait bound `&mut sqlx::Transaction<'_, sqlx::Postgres>: sqlx::Executor<'_>` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `sqlx::Executor<'c>`:
  <&'c mut sqlx::PgConnection as sqlx::Executor<'c>>
  <&'c mut sqlx::sqlx_postgres::PgListener as sqlx::Executor<'c>>
  <&'c mut sqlx::AnyConnection as sqlx::Executor<'c>>
  <&sqlx::Pool<DB> as sqlx::Executor<'p>> [E0277]
rustc: required by a bound introduced by this call [E0277]

Does this boil down to doing some sort of type casting? Curious if this would be considered a limitation or if it actually makes sense for the compiler to think these two expressions are different objects.


I didn't think that transaction was a pointer to begin with

What you're missing is that Transaction implements Deref and DerefMut.  Rust can auto-deref via these traits when you attempt to invoke a method on a value that implements Deref, but you can also explicitly deref using the * operator.  &mut then takes a reference to this value, which is a PgConnection in this case.

transaction is type Transaction<Postgres>.
*transaction is type PgConnection.
&mut *transaction is type &mut PgConnection.

Because sqlx implements these traits, this allows you to invoke any (non-consuming) method of the underlying database connection on a Transaction value transparently, similar to how you can transparently execute any (non-consuming) methods of the slice type on a Vec.
Note that reborrowing (&* and &mut *) are common patterns when working with types that implement Deref (and maybe DerefMut).  Some examples:

Given some_vec that is a Vec<T>, &*some_vec gives you a &[T].
Given some_box that is a Box<T>, &*some_box gives you a &T.


There are a couple of moving parts here. You didn't specify version of sqlx you are working with, but from the error you are getting I assume this is 0.7.x, and so my answer will be targeted at this version.
Query::execute takes as a parameter an Executor. Note the following section from Executor's documentation:

Implemented for the following:

&Pool
&mut Connection

The Executor impls for Transaction and PoolConnection have been deleted because they cannot exist in the new crate architecture without rewriting the Executor trait entirely. To fix this breakage, simply add a dereference where an impl Executor is expected, as they both dereference to the inner connection type which will still implement it:

&mut transaction -> &mut *transaction
&mut connection -> &mut *connection


Since Transaction implements Deref<Target = <DB as Database>::Connection>, you have to dereference and reborrow it (that is create &mut *transaction), to pass it to execute.

solid answer, I found @cdhowie's slightly more informative but they're essentially the same answer. Thank you for the explanation!
